# Joomla getItems default Pagination

Tags: joomla, model, pagination, components, large-data

Can anyone tell me if the `getItems()` function in the model automatically adds the globally set LIMIT before it actions the query (from `getListQuery()`).  Joomla is really struggling, seemingly trying to cache the entire results (over 1 million records here!).

After looking in **/libraries/legacy/model/list.php** AND **/libraries/legacy/model/legacy.php** it appears that `getItems()` does add LIMIT to setQuery using `$this->getState('list.limit')` before it sends the results to the cache but if this is the case - why is Joomla struggling so much.

So what's going on?  How come phpMyAdmin can return the limited results within a second and Joomla just times out?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does add the pagination automatically.

Its struggling is most likely due to a large dataset (i.e. 1000+ items returned in the collection) and many lookup fields: the content modules for example join as many as 10 tables, to get author names etc.

This can be a real killer, I had queries running for over one second with a dedicated server and only 3000 content items. One tag cloud component we found could take as long as 45 seconds to return a keywords list. If this is the situation (a lot of records and many joins), your only way out is to further limit the filters in the options to see if you can get some faster results (for example, limiting to articles in the last 3 months can reduce the time needed dramatically).

But if this is not sufficient or not viable, you're left with writing a new optimized query in a new model, which ultimately will bring the best performance optimization of any other optimization. In writing the query, consider leveraging the database specific optimizations, i.e. adding indexes, full-text indexes and only use joins if you really need them.

Also consider that joins must never grow with the number of fields, translations or else.
A constant query is easy for the db engine to optimize and cache, whilst a dynamic query will never be as efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you have one million records, you'll most definitely want to do as Riccardo is suggesting, override and optimize the model.

JModelList runs the query twice, once for the pagination numbers and then for the display query itself. You'll want to carefully inherit from [JModellist](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/e220fd70676b565831ebf043fe6c4b238a3e7ea7/libraries/legacy/model/list.php) to avoid the pagination query.

Also, the [articles query](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/e220fd70676b565831ebf043fe6c4b238a3e7ea7/components/com_content/models/articles.php#L155) is notorious for it's joins. You can definitely lose some of that slowdown (doubt you are using the contacts link, for example).

If all articles are visible to public, you can [remove the ACL check](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/e220fd70676b565831ebf043fe6c4b238a3e7ea7/components/com_content/models/articles.php#L254) - that's pretty costly.

There is no DBA from the West or the East who is able to explain why all of those [GROUP BY's](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/e220fd70676b565831ebf043fe6c4b238a3e7ea7/components/com_content/models/articles.php#L496) are needed, either.

Losing those things will help considerably. In fact, building your query from scratch might be best.

Comment: Hi, Thanks - I've just ditched JPagination and it's loading so much quicker!  The thing is - I want to keep JPagination but change the getTotal function so that instead of counting the rows from a full query it will get the database to do a "select count" instead.  Can anyone recommend how to do this without hacking core Joomla code?